# Joomla clean current page (com_content) cache

Tags: joomla

How can I delete current's page com_content cache ?

Something what I tried, but not working.

```
$cache =& JFactory::getCache();
$cache->clean(413, "com_content");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$cache =& JFactory::getCache();
$cache->cleanCache(413, "com_content");
?>
```

Comment: Isn't that same code what he have already tried but did not work?

Comment: thanks, btw I forgot to ask, how to get id of current page(com_content) id ?

Comment: @Ville Rouhiainen it's id of current page, i need cache items (groups) id.

Comment: @samitha can you please give a more detail on JCache, i'm not really which one is id for i.e i have this `["mod_slaideris"]=>
  object(JCacheStorageHelper)#331 (3) {
    ["group"]=>
    string(13) "mod_slaideris"
    ["size"]=>
    string(4) "2.96"
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
  }` and which one here is id of `mod_slideris` ?